# how to define commands within custom environment

Tags: environments

I am working on a custom `.cls` for typesetting my CV. I am trying to create a custom environment to provide formatting for job/education history. I would like to specify it as follows:

```
\begin{cvsection}
  \cvdate{xx-xx-xxxx}
  \cvcompany{Some company & Co.}
  \cvposition{Toilet cleaner}
  \cvcomment{I love cleanin' dem toilets!}
\end{cvsection}
```

So I've defined my environment and tried to use `\newcommand...` within the environment definition. LaTeX doesn't like that so what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One purpose of organizing an environment in that way is to allow flexibility in the input.

You don't need to define the commands inside the environment; a frequently used strategy is the following:

```
\newcommand{\cvdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvdate}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvcompany}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvcompany}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvposition}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvposition}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvcomment}[1]{\renewcommand{\givencvcomment}{#1}}
\newcommand{\givencvdate}{REQUIRED!}
\newcommand{\givencvcompany}{REQUIRED!}
\newcommand{\givencvposition}{REQUIRED!}
\newcommand{\givencvcomment}{} % this is optional

\newenvironment{cvsection}
 {\begin{flushleft}}
 {\textbf{\givencvdate}\\
  \givencvcompany\\
  \givencvposition
  \ifx\empty\givencvcomment\else\\[.5ex] \textit{\givencvcomment}\fi
  \end{flushleft}}
```

In this way the order one specifies the data in the environment is irrelevant. Let's see a couple of examples

```
\begin{cvsection}
  \cvdate{xx-xx-xxxx}
  \cvcompany{Some company \& Co.}
  \cvposition{Toilet cleaner}
  \cvcomment{I love cleanin' dem toilets!}
\end{cvsection}

\begin{cvsection}
  \cvposition{Toilet cleaner}
  \cvdate{xx-xx-xxxx}
  \cvcompany{Another company \& Co.}
\end{cvsection}
```

Of course you have to adjust the definition of `cvsection` to suit your needs.

[image]

Comment: basically I was doing it wrong (which was what I thought). Thank-you.

Comment: @bugsduggan You *can* define the commands in the environment, so that they can't be used outside. Just move the block of definitions in the "beginning" part of `cvsection` (between `{` and `\begin{flushleft}`) but remember to write `##1` instead of `#1`.

Comment: @egreg How could it be done using `LaTeX3` syntaxis? Do I still need to use the `##1` form?

Comment: @Dox Yes, there's no difference in that respect: it's a TeX general fact. I see no real advantage in doing it in `expl3` syntax, except perhaps the test about emptyness.