# latex environment writing generate tikz code but insert it later - maybe with tikz keys

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, environments, pgfkeys

I'm trying to write an environment where the user should be able to insert some commands inside the environment (easy by defining new commands inside the environment) but the output of the commands should only be inserted at the end.

My example:

```
\begin{myEnv}
    lorem ipsum
    \newCommand{1}{2}
\end{myEnv}
```

Where the definition of `myEnv` looks like this:

```
\newenvironment{myEnv}%
{%
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}%
}%
{%
    \end{pNiceMatrix}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    <insert the code generated by "newCommand" here>
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve something like this? (I have no idea yet)

(Something explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76160/how-to-define-commands-within-custom-environment#76169) does not work, since one should be able to use `\newCommand` multiple times inserting the corresponding code multiple times)

EDIT: My idea now is to do something with pgf keys like the following

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \pgfkeys{/drawing/.code={}}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \pgfkeys{/drawing/.add={\draw (1,1) -- (2,2);}{}}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \pgfkeys{/drawing}
        \draw (1,2) -- (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

But the code contained in `drawing` is not executed on `\pgfkeys{/drawing}`. Am I doing something wrong or wont this idea work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are stuck with version 3.6 of `nicematrix` (see [this previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547932/nicematrix-codeafter-tikz-not-working)), I can give you a solution *ad hoc* with a definition of a command `\MyCodeAfter` which will do the job for version 3.6 of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % version 3.6 !
\usepackage{tikz}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \MyCodeAfter { m }
  { \tl_gput_right:Nn \g__nm_code_after_tl { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    $\begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        9 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    %
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9
    \MyCodeAfter{\tikz \draw (2-2) circle (2mm) ;}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

However, this is not in the spirit of LaTeX3 because it uses the private internal `\g__nm_code_after_tl`. Such an internal should not be used excepted by `nicematrix` itself. Moreover, in more recent versions of `nicematrix`, this internal has been renamed `\g__nicematrix_code_after_tl`. The prefix `_nicematrix_` has been registered to the LaTeX3 team.